# Remove object from embedded array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to remove a document from an array. My schema is as so:

```
var FarmSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: String, unique: true, index: true }, //CPH FIELD
  cph:{type: String, unique: true},
  post_code: { type: String },
  robust_farm_type: { type: String },
  less_favoured_area_status: { type: String },
  organic_status: { type: Boolean },
  e_animal_records: { type: Boolean },
  e_ketosis_data: { type: Boolean },
  e_milk_conductivity_data: { type: Boolean },
  e_milk_data_yield: { type: Boolean },
  allocated_products : [{
    date : { type: Date, index: true, required: true  }, // Date - to be filtered on query . i.e date between x and y
    theraputic_group : { type: String, required: true }, //product category i.e. Antimicrobial
    volume : { type: Number, required: true } //Generic number to represent either quantity of tube or ml
    }]
})
```

I am trying to remove a doc by its _id within `allocated_products`. Looked at a few examples and tried a few alternatives but can't get it working for me. So far I have this:

```
var query = { _id: req.params.id }; // id being the farm ID
  //Tried also {$elemMatch: {_id : '568bed3d4470f5e81519203b'}}
  var update = { $pull: { 'allocated_products._id': req.params.product }};

  Farm.findOneAndUpdate(query,update)
    .exec(function(err, customer) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      console.log(customer);
      res.json(customer);
    })
```

This doesn't remove the doc and I get this error:

```
MongoError: exception: cannot use the part (allocated_products of allocated_products._id) to traverse the element
```

Is the only way to achieve this by doing a loop after a find() query? I would have thought there would have been a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know $pull doesn't support dot notation.

Try to do it with the following query:

```
var update = { $pull: { allocated_products: {_id: req.params.product } } };
```